# Path issue that makes a CSS file not read (React App)

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a file named custom.css which override materialize.css,

It's imported in public/index.html with this line :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css" />
```

On a route like /account, it works fine, in the browser I can see the http://localhost:3000/custom.css loaded,

But on a route like /user/:username, the CSS file becomes http://localhost:3000/user/custom.css so it doesn't work,

I did my project with create-react-app, and I'm not using a bundler (maybe there's one with the boilerplate),

I don't even know where to start to resolve this issue,

Comment: How and where do you include your css file ?

Comment: in public/index.html with this line: <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css" />, I don't know how to make it a relative path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you use such import path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css">
```

You have to replace  path with :

```
href="/custom.css"
```

Comment: thank you so much, it works now, i'll accept your answer when i will be able to :)